# Insert and run nuget Package Manager Console command through macros

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, nuget-package

I would like to create a macro in Visual Studio 2010 which:

-opens the Package Manager Console

-runs a command in it

The macro recording tool only generates the code for the first issue:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.PackageManagerConsole")
```

Any thoughts on how to inject and run a command?

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62(v=vs.100).aspx

Somethimes, it is helpful, ot try searching in google with subject: Run Macro in VS 2010